# ngCordova geolocation with ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, geolocation, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am trying to use ngCordova geolocation with my ionic app. I did the following:

1) Bower installed and included ngcordova.min.js in index.html

2) Injected 'ngCordova' as a dependency in my angular app.module.

```
angular
.module('app', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
.run(runConfig);
```

3) Added the dependency in my controller

```
SomeController.$inject = ['$location', '$cordovaGeolocation',
                          '$ionicPlatform']
```

4) This is what my controller looks like:

```
 (function() {
    'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.submission')
    .controller('SomeController', SomeController);

  SomeController.$inject = ['$location', '$cordovaGeolocation', '$ionicPlatform'];

  function SomeController($location, $element, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicPlatform) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.place = '';
    vm.address = {
      'latitude' : null,
      'longitude' : null
    }

    vm.initialize = initialize;
    vm.getAddress = getAddress;

    function initialize() {
       var input = (document.getElementById('location-search'));
       var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox((input));
    }

    function getAddress(){
      var posOptions = {timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
            $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
            .then(function(position){
                var lat  = position.coords.latitude
                var long = position.coords.longitude
                console.log('lat', lat);
                console.log('long', long);
            }, function(error){
                console.log('error:', error);
            });
    }

  }

})();
```

5) Function getAddress() is called on ng-click of a button.

while i test the app on a web browser (google chrome) I get the following error

```
TypeError: $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition is not a function
at SomeController.getAddress (SomeController.js:29)
at $parseFunctionCall (ionic.bundle.js:21044)
at ionic.bundle.js:53458
at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:23100)
at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23199)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:53457)
at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:11713)
at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2863)
at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2852)
at HTMLDocument.tapMouseUp (ionic.bundle.js:2925)
```

Can someone help me here, what is wrong with my code? Is it supposed to work only on mobile devices? I tried on a android device and it didnt work.

Comment: try if this helps , http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ngcordova-with-geolocation-not-working/18083/3

Comment: Please post the entire controller or at least a larger portion of it. Perhaps there is a dependency issue of the `$inject` not working right. Try commenting out the entire function and just a do an alert or console.log / $log.debug to see if anything shows up in the controller. I noticed a missing `;` at the end of the `var posOptions = {timeout...` line also.

Comment: updated my question with the complete controller code

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same code,, try to replace with these codes

```
 SomeController.$inject = ['$scope','$location', '$cordovaGeolocation', '$ionicPlatform'];

  function SomeController($scope,$location, $element, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicPlatform) {
  var posOptions = {timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true,maximumAge: 0 };
  $scope.where = function(){
    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
      .then(function(position){
          console.log(position);
          $scope.lat1  = position.coords.latitude
          $scope.lng1 = position.coords.longitude

      }, function(error){
          console.log('error:', error);
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works in the browser but it goes to the error call back and throws positionError .

Comment: For device do not use .min.js